# How to override the CRUD/list() function? Play! framework

Tags: pagination, playframework, crud

I'm trying to override the list() function of the CRUD module for one of my models.

I found [this](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/32fdeaeb801549e#) on google groups which is essentially the issue i'm having.

Basically I want to filter the list based on certian categories, I tried this:

CONTROLLER

```
public static void list(string category){
    List<Duty> object = Duty.getByCategory(category);
    render(object);
}
```

MODEL

```
public static List<Duty> getByCategory(String category){
    List<Duty> result = Duty.find("select distinct d from Duty d join " +
        "d.category c where c.name = ? order by d.name", category).fetch();
    return result;
}
```

I get the following error:

[image: Template execution error]

How do you overwrite the list action?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are overriding the controller but not the template. The signature of the CRUD list method is [this one](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/modules/crud/app/controllers/CRUD.java#L46), slightly different that yours:

```
public static void list(int page, String search, String searchFields, String orderBy, String order) {
        ObjectType type = ObjectType.get(getControllerClass());
        notFoundIfNull(type);
        if (page < 1) {
            page = 1;
        }
        List<Model> objects = type.findPage(page, search, searchFields, orderBy, order, (String) request.args.get("where"));
        Long count = type.count(search, searchFields, (String) request.args.get("where"));
        Long totalCount = type.count(null, null, (String) request.args.get("where"));
        try {
            render(type, objects, count, totalCount, page, orderBy, order);
        } catch (TemplateNotFoundException e) {
            render("CRUD/list.html", type, objects, count, totalCount, page, orderBy, order);
        }
    }
```

You will notice that render() is passing many more parameters that you do, and probably they are not optional. Try to provide values for them.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the CRUD list method, and add filters passing many parameters in **where** for example:

```
public static void list(int page, String search, String searchFields, String orderBy, String order) {
    ObjectType type = ObjectType.get(getControllerClass());
    notFoundIfNull(type);
    if (page < 1) {
        page = 1;
    }
    String where = "nameAttribute =" + value;

    List<Model> objects = type.findPage(page, search, searchFields, orderBy, order, where);
    Long count = type.count(search, searchFields, where);
    Long totalCount = type.count(null, null, where);
    try {
        render(type, objects, count, totalCount, page, orderBy, order);
    } catch (TemplateNotFoundException e) {
        render("CRUD/list.html", type, objects, count, totalCount, page, orderBy, order);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call that override method from `view(xtml)`.

```
<form action="@{Controler.overrideList()}"  method="POST">
```

And use previous code,and add filters passing many parameters in `where = "..."`