# Play! Framework, customising the CRUD list() function

Tags: playframework, crud, playframework-1.x

I want to filter my list function by certain parameters, looking at the [CRUD.java controller](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/modules/crud/app/controllers/CRUD.java) :

```
List<Model> objects = type.findPage(page, search, searchFields, orderBy, order, (String) request.args.get("where"));
Long count = type.count(search, searchFields, (String) request.args.get("where"));
Long totalCount = type.count(null, null, (String) request.args.get("where"));
```

It seems to be filtering based on the where parameter in the query string, but I can't find any documentation on what format the where clause should be in, or how to use it?

Comment: see this usefull answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827427/how-to-override-the-crud-list-function-play-framework][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827427/how-to-override-the-crud-list-function-play-framework

Comment: So ... should this be closed as a duplicate or not?

Comment: Yes, how do you close a question.

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple JPA query where clause.

For example if you have a User model with username properties, you could make a where clause such as this:

```
"user.username = 'lucernae'"
```

It will list all the User model instances which username equals 'lucernae'